# Lambda script to move files from glacier to cloud drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-glacier, amazon-clouddrive

I have over a TB of photos backed up in AWS glacier. However, cloud drive seems to be the better choice for this going forward. Ie it has no retrieval fees, no recovery times and generally a more convenient interface.

Now to minimize cost of the file moving process I thought I'd create a slow retrieval (within Glacier recovery free tier) to S3, get retrievals notified via SNS to a Node Lambda function and then upload the file from S3 to cloud drive via its API.

Two questions:

1. The cloud drive API docs state that all clients/apps need to be approved. Surely that is not needed for my little script?
2. Is there a nodejs library that gives me an API abstraction to upload files to cloud drive?

Comment: The [terms of service](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=201376540) also say *"You may use the Service only to store, retrieve, manage, and access Your Files for personal, non-commercial purposes using the features and functionality we make available."*

Comment: Not sure where you are going with this comment? I do use all these services for personal, non commercial purposes. I backup all raw and jpeg versions of my photos.